# stripping out all characters from a string, leaving numbers

Tags: php, numbers

Hay, i have a string like this:

```
v8gn5.8gnr4nggb58gng.g95h58g.n48fn49t.t8t8t57
```

I want to strip out all the characters leaving just numbers (and .s)

Any ideas how to do this? Is there a function prebuilt?

thanks

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $str);
```

replace substrings that do not consist of digits or . with nothing.

Here's how it works:

1. `preg_replace` is a PHP function that searches a string for a pattern and replaces it with a given replacement string.
2. The first parameter in `preg_replace` is the regular expression pattern to search for. In this case, the pattern is `'/[^0-9.]+/'`, which matches any character that is not a digit or a dot. The ^ character inside square brackets means "not", so `[^0-9.]` means any character that is not a digit or a dot. The `+` sign means one or more occurrences of the previous character or character group, in this case [^0-9.].
3. The second parameter in `preg_replace` is the replacement string. In this case, the replacement string is an empty string ''. So any character that matches the pattern in the first parameter will be replaced with an empty string.
4. The third parameter in `preg_replac` is the input string to search and modify. In this case, the input string is represented by the variable `$str`.

So, this line of code will remove any character from the input string $str that is not a digit or a dot, and return the modified string with only digits and dots.

Comment: Depending what your doing the above function need to scape the dot. That really give me a lot of troubble during a large db importing.

Comment: No, in the square brackets, characters are themselves (mostly, except ^ in the beginning to mean NOT, - between to other characters to mean RANGE, names of classes, non-printing digraphs like \t, \n,... ). Anyway, in this case, the . is not special inside the [ ]. So it would be nice to explain what you were doing that wanted to escape the dot.

Answer (score 7):

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Robin, there's no need. I've tested it before posting and works OK.

Comment: @Robin, you would need to escape the period if it were outside of the brackets []. inside the square brackets the period is not treated as a special character

Comment: @Robin: The text inside the [] is defining a set of characters; it doesn't really make much sense for the '.' character to mean any character in that context.

Answer (score 2):

```
$input = 'some str1ng 234';
$newString = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", '', $input);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the shortest one:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str);
```

\D = all non-digits.

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy my curiosity I asked about the speed of the proposed answers and as shown in [preg_replace speed optimisation/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118152/pregreplace-speed-optimisation/) it is (much) faster to use `str_replace()` than `preg_replace()`.

So you might want to use `str_replace()` instead.

Comment: But you can't really use `str_replace()` in this case, unless you want to hardcode all characters which are not numbers.

Comment: @kemp, hm... yes that's true. That would be too much :)