# Stripping a string of characters in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [stripping out all characters from a string, leaving numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118000/stripping-out-all-characters-from-a-string-leaving-numbers)

I have something produced by an API that looks like: `34 Canadian Dollars`. I'm trying to get rid of the alphabetical characters and keep only the numeric characters. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that you're working with currencies and that the number may contain a comma or decimal point, you should use this instead:

```
preg_match('/([0-9\.,]+)/', $input, $matches);

// Output the amount.
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.,]/', '', $input);
```

HTH.

Edited to accept commas and periods.

Comment: This doesn't take into account decimal points and commas. See my solution below. He's trying to use the Google Calculator API to convert currencies which will result in decimal points.

Comment: That's easily fixed and IMO still much nicer than using preg_match. :)

Comment: You're right except that should the string contain a dot somewhere else (i.e. "34.31 Canadian Dollars."), your preg_replace would return "34.31." while my example above would return "34.31".

Answer (score 0):

[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) would be perfect for this.

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]*) *$/", $inputStr, $results);
echo $results[1];
```

Also, this [online regex tester](http://www.quanetic.com/Regex) is a great place to test out other regex patterns.

Comment: preg_replace would probably work better, as per @jupaju's answer.

Comment: I completely disagree. If there are decimals, preg_replace won't work. Even by adding a decimal point to the list "34.12 Canadian Dollars." would become "34.12." With that said, this preg_match doesn't take decimal points or commas into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an integer you are trying to collect you can use `(int) $input`

Answer (score 0):

Well, i dont know your purpose, but if numbers are always in the beginning of the string, you can use casting.

```
$int = (int)"34 Canadian Dollars";
```

OR

```
$string = "34 Canadian Dollars";
$number = (int)$string
```

hope that helps. the preg_replace in the other answer will also do the job.