# How to remove specified character from a string using php

Tags: php

I have a string `(994)773-2296` or `(+919)947-732296`.

I want to remove `(` , `)` , `-` and `+` from the above numbers to get the exact phone numbers.

How can I achieve this. Is there any method in php to do so?

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118000/stripping-out-all-characters-from-a-string-leaving-numbers - How to leave only numbers in a string.

Comment: `str_replace('old', 'new', $yourString);` but in your scenario I would suggest `preg_replace($pattern, '', $yourString);` where $pattern is a Regex pattern that should look something like this: `'[\(\)-\+]'`